# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings retornando valores diferentes em ambientes diferentes

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure

Não sei muito o que postar pra ajudar na pergunta, então se quiser saber mais é só falar nos comentários.

No `web.config`, dentro de *appSettings*, tem a tag `<add key="apiManagerUrl" value="http://minha-api.azurewebsites.net/api/" />`.
Executando local ela retorna o que está no value, mas quando publico no serviço do Azure ela está retornando um link esdrúxulo: `https://microsoft-apiapp37dce4952f834c67996305734fc0303e.azurewebsites.net/api/`.

Eu sei que o `web.config` está sendo atualizado quando publico o serviço porque precisei alterar a tag `customErrors` para identificar o problema.
Tanto a `apiManagerUrl` quanto o serviço que precisa chamar ela estão publicados na Azure.

Comment: O azure tem um tipo web.config no painel de controlel do site,tente configurar por la. Eu tive o mesmo problema,so que o meu problema foi com a connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do seu WebApp, na opção "AppSettings", você encontrará não apenas configurações pertinentem à hospedagem, como versão do .NET Framework, como também algumas transformações que seu web.config deve sofrer após ser publicado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E isso é muito bacana! Pois você pode, e deve, manter localmente as configurações para que seua aplicação, em tempo de desenvolvimento, esteja configurara para seus ambientes locais/dev. E, ao publicar, automaticamente irá apontas para os destinos respectivos como, se for um ambiente de testes, irá transformar seu web.config para suas APIs, ou bancos de dados de teste. E o mesmo se publicar então em produção.

Desta forma não irá acontecer se esquecer de trocar as configurações antes de subir uma aplicação.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigado! Aproveitando a resposta, pra que serve a opção `Slot setting`?

Comment: @DanielDutra, como é outro assunto, posta outra pergunta que respondo lá pra vc. ;)